# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-iam

I am following this tutorial to enable my django application to upload the file directly to S3.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

When created a new IAM user, I enabled the full access to my S3.  **AmazonS3FullAccess**

But when i uploaded the file I still got the error of

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I tried to add a policy to my S3 bucket then.

But i constantly got the error of Policy has invalid action

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Principal": { "AWS": "[my-IAM user]" }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[s3-bucket-name]",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "home/",
                    "home/${aws:username}/*"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Principal": { "AWS": "[my-IAM user]" }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]/home/${aws:username}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]/home/${aws:username}/*"
        ],
        "Principal": { "AWS": "[my-IAM user]" }
    }
]
```

}

What exactly should i do then?

Comment: Rather than trying to debug your policy, I'd suggest trying to determine why the app received `Access Denied` because that is the proper way to provide access. How is the app receiving credentials? Is it running on an EC2 instance with an associated role, or are the credentials stored locally to the app?